# How to load .html file without loading angular 5 js (vendor, main.bundle etc ..) files?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am doing an angular 5 project. there I have to show terms and conditions page without loading angular 5 js files. such as vendor, main bundle, some other files.

I want to display the tc.html file only without help of angular route. I added a screenshot here. placed terms-and-conditions-en.html under index.html. please provide me a good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just  serve your  html  file. For example  you can put it into public folder  and open in in browser  using it's name:

```
localhost:3000/terms-and-conditions-en.html
```

Comment: where do i place static html in angular 5?

Comment: I think you can try  assets folder

Comment: in this case you can access  it  on localhost:3000/assets/terms-and-conditions-en.html